# Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter special characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that has spring security configured using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. The problem I'm having is at .failureUrl. If I define it like this

```
failureUrl("/login?error")
```

and in my page if the error is present a message is shown. The login form is at the bottom of the page and I want the user to remain there when he is redirected via the failureUrl. So, I changed the url to

```
"/login?error#id"
```

where id is the id of the error message div. If I do this, the user is redirected to

```
/login#id
```

the ?error part is omitted completely. What am I doing wrong? Are there special characters that need to be escaped in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

**Later edit:**

I found the problem: I needed to add "/login" in the permitAll antmatchers.

Comment: If you have solved it yourself, remove your question or post solution as answer if you think it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ?error part was omitted completely because I didn't have /login in the permitAll antmatchers, therefore

```
/login?error#id
```

was redirected to

```
/login#id
```

because

```
/login
```

was set as the loginPage in my configuration.